# How can plus a list of lists in prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

I need a predicate which plus of a list of lists in prolog using pure logic and natural number notation.
For example for the predicate :

`?-totalPlus([ [s(0)],[s(0),s(0)],[s(s(0))] ], Res).`

The result must be:

```
Res= s(s(s(s(s(0))))).
```

This is my implementation but it only returns the plus of the first list:

```
    plusNat(0,X,X).
    plusNat(s(X),Y,s(Z)):-plusNat(X,Y,Z).

    plusList([],0).
    plusList([X|Xs], S) :- plusList(Xs,SXs), plusNat(X,SXs,S).

    totalPlus([],_).
    totalPlus([X|Xs],Y):-totalPlus(Xs,_), plusList(X,Y).
    ------------------

    ?-totalPlus([ [s(0)],[s(0),s(0)],[s(s(0))] ], Res).
      Res= s(0).
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Apply the concept you used in `plusList` a second time.

Comment: using another predicate plusList2 called in plusList for example?

Comment: yes, that is correct.

Comment: i already prove and it doesn't work =(
can you put an example?

Answer (score 1):

I Finally added a plus predicate to accumulate the result , it is a possible solution and it works :

```
plusNat(0,X,X).
plusNat(s(X),Y,s(Z)):-plusNat(X,Y,Z).
plusList([],0).
plusList([X|Xs],S) :- plusList(Xs,SXs), plusNat(X,SXs,S).
totalPlus([],0).
totalPlus([X|Xs],Y):-totalPlus(Xs,Z), plusList(X,K), plusNat(K,Z,Y).
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to implement the `plusList/2` with a helper predicate `plusList/3` that uses an accumulator, like:

```
plusList(L, S) :-
    plusList(L, 0, S).

plusList([], S, S).
plusList([H|T], Si, So) :-
    plusNat(H, Si, S),
    plusList(T, S, So).
```

The nice thing is that we can make use of this helper predicate to avoid double work when we add the sums of the sublists together for `totalPlus`:

```
totalPlus(LL, S) :-
    totalPlus(LL, 0, S).

totalPlus([], S, S).
totalPlus([H|T], Si, So) :-
    plusList(H, Si, S),
    totalPlus(T, S, So).
```